# A triangle having coordinates $(a\cos\phi, a \sin\phi) , (a\cos\theta, a\sin\theta) , (a\cos\psi, a \sin\psi)$....

Tags: polar-coordinates

A triangle having coordinates $(a\cos\phi, a \sin\phi) , (a\cos\theta, a\sin\theta) , (a\cos\psi, a \sin\psi)$  having its area  $$ \Delta = 2a^2 \sin\frac{\theta - \phi}{2}\sin\frac{\phi -\psi}{2}\sin\frac{\psi -\theta}{2}$$

Please suggest when will be the area of this triangle is maximum. Thanks.

Comment: (elliptic-curves)? I don't think so.

Comment: Your vertices are all just vertices on a circle of radius $a$. If you have a circle of radius $a$ and you need to choose three points on it to form a triangle, when do you think the area will be maximum?

Comment: Hint (without using calculus): Assume two of the points are $A$ and $B$. Call the distance between them $d$. Where should we put $C$, the third point, to maximize the area? Well, the area is $d\cdot\mathrm{height}$, so we need to maximize the height—that is, we need to maximize the distance $C$ is from $\overline{AB}$. Thus, $C$ should be directly opposite the midpoint of $A$ and $B$. Similarly, $A$ should be directly opposite the midpoint of $B$ and $C$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\theta=0$ without loss of generality then setting the partial derivatives to 0 and solving yields $\phi=2\pi/3$, $\psi=4\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let two vertexes be fixed and taken as a base. Then the position of the third vertex that maximizes the area is the one that maximizes the altitude, i.e. on the mediatrix. So the triangle must be isosceles.

Repeating for the three sides, the triangle must be equilateral and the vertexes are spaced by 120°.